# How can I make a specific login for specific group with Django's `authenticate()`?

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication

Hello I have been looking through the documentation in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users. However, it shows only how to authenticate all `User`.

I have grouped some my `User` now I want only specific `User` to login in a specific form. How can I achieve that?

Additionally, when should I use `Permissions` and when should I use `Groups`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to create a custom decorator to do it, why? because I think this method is easy to understand how to work with Group than using Permissions.

an example in your `yourapp/decorators.py`:

> You can see, here we focusing on `if ... request.user.groups.filter(name='moderator')` to handle the group.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def moderator_login_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() \
                and request.user.groups.filter(name='moderator').exists():
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            context = {
                'title': _('403 Forbidden'),
                'message': _('You are not allowed to access this page!')
            }
            # you can also return redirect to another page here.
            return render(request, 'path/to/error_page.html', context)
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

Ho to use in your `views.py`?

```
from yourapp.decorators import moderator_login_required

@moderator_login_required
def dashboard(request):
    #do_stuff
```

Or, if you working with CBV *(Class Bassed View)*, you can using `@method_decorator`, eg:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

from yourapp.decorators import moderator_login_required

class DashboardView(TemplateView):

    @method_decorator(moderator_login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DashboardView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helpful..

Comment: Hey it is kinda works, however `request.user` refers to the superuser `admin` user and not the user I authenticate. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Never mind it is working, I did an `authenticate()` but I did not logged in using `login()`. Terimakasih!